# Map Reduce by date with RockMongo admin panel

Tags: mongodb, dictionary

I am trying to find the best way to clean my Mongo DB from old rows. This is the row structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("52adb7fb12e20f2e2400be38"),
    "1": "2013-12-15 06: 07: 20",
    "2": "1",
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "ID",
    "6": "139.195.98.240",
    "7": "",
    "8": "youtube",
    "9": NumberInt(0),
    "10": "",
    "11": ""
}
```

The date field is this.1. So I want to set a delte method for all rows older then 30 days.

So I figured out that a map can help with this task, if there are any other suggestion please feel free to suggest.

This is the map function that i am trying to run:

```
{
    mapreduce : "delete_rows",
    map : function () {
        var delete_date = new Date();
        delete_date.setDate(delete_date.getDate()-7);
        row_date = new Date(this.1);
        if(row_date <  delete_date){ 
            emit(this._id,{date: this.1}, {all_data: this}); 
        }
    },
    out : {
        "delete_rows"
    },
    keeptemp:false,
    jsMode : false,
    verbose : false 
}
```

I get the following error at rockmongo query window:

```
Criteria must be a valid JSON object
```

Can anyone jelp me with this syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Means you want to delete all documents where value(date) of 1 is less than 1 month, right?

Comment: Yes, for this specific exmaple i wanted to delete rows that are older then 1 week..